# Mock Auth::user() in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, mocking

I have this code:

```
// ...
Passport::actingAs($this->user);
$mock = Mockery::mock(User::class);
$mock->shouldReceive('myMethodName')->andReturn(157);
Auth::shouldReceive('user')->once()->andReturn($mock);
```

If I call

```
Auth::user()->myMethodName(); // It returns 157
```

But if I call (or another one method of Auth)

```
  Auth::id();
  // it throws Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException : Method Mockery_2_Illuminate_Auth_AuthManager::id() does not exist on this mock object
```

Where is the problem ?

Comment: Try adding this to the `setUp` method of the base test case: `\Mockery::getConfiguration()->allowMockingNonExistentMethods(false);`.

Comment: I tried this. So i have another exception `Mockery\Exception : Mockery's configuration currently forbids mocking the method user as it does not exist on the class or object being mocked
`

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the answer:

```
$this->user = factory(User::class)->create();
Passport::actingAs($this->user);

$obj = Mockery::mock($this->user)
    ->makePartial()
    ->shouldReceive('myMethodName')
    ->andReturn(123)
    ->getMock();

Auth::setUser($obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use `Auth()` like:

```
Auth::user()->id;
```

Comment: I tried it. there is another problem **Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException : Received Mockery_1_App_User::getAttribute(), but no expectations were specified
**

Answer (score -1):

For newer versions of Laravel:

```
$user = (new User)->forceFill([
    'name' => 'Their name',
    'email' => 'email@example.com',
]);

$user->email
// output: email@example.com
```

Comment: How does that address the use of `Auth::user()`? And regardless of that, you should use factories to create fake models.